# DocuSign Connect Profiles

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

I need to know how docusign connect profiles work. As far as my understanding, if I have multiple connect profiles, the notification will be sent to all URLs in all the profiles.

For example, consider I've two connect profiles for production and development purposes. When a document is sent to a recipient, this notification will be sent to both production and development URLs.

Could anybode correct me, if I'm wrong? Your input will be of great help.

Thanks,
Vasanth

Answer (score 2):

Correct, you can have multiple connect profiles.

Each one contains a url for your webhook that will be called by the DocuSign platform when your configuration criteria are met.

All active connect profiles will be called when an applicable event occurs.